# How to malloc a char[] properly without memory leaks

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

How do I fix this line to work with my code. I know in C99 variable-length arrays are allowed, but I need to use malloc to fix this line. How would I go about doing that. `char stack[strlen(input)];` (I am not using C99, by the way)

Comment: Note if `stack` is supposed to hold a copy of the string `input`, then it needs to be of size `strlen(input)+1` to hold the terminating null byte.

Comment: What part of the chapter in your book/tutorial about malloc is unclear, more specifically? You should clarify such when asking about utterly fundamental stuff that can easily be looked up in a beginner-level book.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `stack` as pointer and use `malloc`.

```
char *stack = malloc(strlen(input));
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to add that it's recommended to always check the value of a pointer you just allocated with malloc.

You can do it this way :

```
char *stack = malloc(strlen(input));
if (stack == NULL) {
  return -1;
}
```

You can modify the `return -1;` with whatever you want depending where you are using this part of code. -1 being what some people usually return when an error occurs.

**Why do that?**

The `malloc()` function can fail allocating memory space in case RAM is full for example. This doesn't happen often but it has to be catched for code correctness.